# Why ID is not taking while two selection boxes in the form?

Tags: javascript

I have two selection boxes in the form listing below, Both have different id "language" and "time". Now the problem is my script is not showing error correctly. I put Border color to show error.
Can someone help me with this?

```
<div class="field_wrap">
  <select name="language" id="language" onblur="validateSelect(language)" class="select_promo">
    <option value="0" disabled selected>Prefered Language</option>
    <option value="1">English</option>
    <option value="2">Hindi</option>
    <option value="3">Tamil</option>
    <option value="4">Malayalam</option>
  </select></div>
<div class="field_wrap">
  <select name="time" id="time" onblur="validateSelect(time)" class="select_promo">
    <option value="0" disabled selected>Time to Contact</option>
    <option value="1">8 - 10 AM</option>
    <option value="2">10 - 12 AM</option>
    <option value="3">12 - 2 PM</option>
    <option value="4">2 - 5 PM</option>
    <option value="5">5 - 8 PM</option>
  </select></div>
</div>
```

My Script :

```
function validateSelect(language) { 
  var myValue = document.getElementById('language').value;
  if(myValue > 0) {
    document.getElementById('language').style.borderColor ='#80c75a';
    document.getElementById('languageError').style.display = "none";
    return true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('language').style.borderColor ='#e35152';
    return false;
  }
}

function validateSelect(time) { 
  var myValue = document.getElementById('time').value;
  if(myValue > 0) {
    document.getElementById('time').style.borderColor ='#80c75a';
    document.getElementById('timeError').style.display = "none";
    return true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('time').style.borderColor ='#e35152';
    return false;
  }
}

// Validate Select

if (!validateSelect(document.getElementById('language'))) {
  document.getElementById('languageError').style.display = "block";
  error++;
}

if (!validateSelect(document.getElementById('time'))) {
  document.getElementById('timeError').style.display = "block";
  error++;
}
```

Comment: If you're not using jQuery remove tag

Comment: Why do you use the jQuery tag if there is no jQuery in your script?

Comment: "*my script is not showing error correctly*" is not a good description of the error. What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? What error messages do you get (if any)?

Comment: You have `document.getElementById('languageError')`, where is the element with ID *languageError*? Similarly, where is *timeError*?

Comment: While selecting language selection box without selecting a value shows error in time selection box . when I refresh the page no error indication while selecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in your code:

1. you declare function `validateSelect` twice
2. you pass there an element while an element id is expected in the function
3. `onblur` event handler in your selects should accept parameter in quotes

Here is what your javascript should look like:

```
function validateSelect(id){ 
  var el = document.getElementById(id),
      myValue = el.value;
  if(myValue > 0){
    el.style.borderColor ='#80c75a';
    document.getElementById(id+'Error').style.display = "none";
     return true;
  }else{
    el.style.borderColor ='#e35152';
    return false;
  }
}

// Validate Select
validateSelect('time');
validateSelect('language');
```

Your onblurs should look like:

`onblur="validateSelect('language')"` and `onblur="validateSelect('time')"`

Check fiddle: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/vatpngu0/)

Comment: I checked the JS fiddle , but it shows red color before the selection.

Comment: Sure! That's because by default your first values in selects are zeros. Your `validateSelect` function colors border red if `myValue` is zero.

Comment: I replaced the code in the site but it shows no error indications before and after selections. I need no borders in default stage, red border in value 0 and green for the selection above 0 values.

Comment: I assume you get greens above 0. At load now there is no color - check this one: https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/z4xv66Lc/.  At 0 there will be reds but you have marked your options with zero value as `disabled` - you have it like `<option value="0" disabled selected>`. So there is no possibility to ever select the zero value for the user.

Comment: yes,  but once any one try to select the box and leave without proper selection at that time shows error in red color.

Comment: Then change your `onblur`s to `onchange`s like so: `onchange="validateSelect('language')"` and `onchange="validateSelect('time')"`

Comment: @ Nikolay Ermakov, One trouble in that code is while submitting the form the validate select (language and time) are not taking.

Comment: Then call validation function also before sending form - see updated https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/vatpngu0/

Comment: @ Nikolay Ermakov,  this is my form am trying to validate..pls  check:: https://jsfiddle.net/ansarmon/y4k4uwqd/

Comment: You didn't add any error divs and that causes a script error when trying to find one by id. So I commented out that code. Also you didn't include jQuery lib in your fiddle. Check https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/y4k4uwqd/1/